# Why do ints have different hex values in python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, hex, scapy

I'm converting some code from python 2.7 to python 3 and I am running into issues with hexadecimal ints.

```
    value = 0x11
    hexdump(value)
python2 output: 11
python3 output: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
```

This hexdump function is from scapy and has worked for all my other hex troubleshooting. Doing chr(0x11) yields the expected value but many scapy functions get called that crash if it's not in type int.

I need a way to get 11 as my hex data with type int. I tried changing the type using

```
    int(value,16) #also tried 0 and 10
```

The issue with this is I get ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 
 '\x11'

Comment: `print(type(0x11))` this shows that `0x11` is `int`

Comment: `chr(0x11)` converts to string with one char which has code `x11` but because there is no font with this code so Python display it as `\x11`. But Python doesn't treat this as a string with four chars (with two digits `1`) and you can't convert it to integer usin `int()`  but `ord('\x11')` which gives integer 17 - in hex it is 11.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`0x11` is an int in both python2 and python3. Perhaps there's some string-handling in your `hexdump` function that's going wrong? Strings are *very* different in python3.

Can you post the code for `hexdump()`?

Based on the comment below by @Cukic0d, if your `hexbytes()` actually wants an array of bytes, this should work: `hexdump(bytes([value]))` -- that converts the length-1 array of ints containing value into a `bytes` object and passes that to `hexdump`.

Comment: Correct. hexdump takes a Scapy Packet or bytes as an input

Comment: hexdump is a scapy function that just prints out the values, I am using it to just check i'm getting the write hex data. Here's the link to the documentation with the hexdump function https://github.com/secdev/scapy/blob/master/scapy/utils.py I'm able to get the correct hex data if i convert to a string or bytes like you say but i need my value to be type int due to other dependencies.

Comment: Looking at that code, `hexdump` calls `bytes_encode()` on its input, expecting it to be a sequence of some type, so I'm pretty sure that code as it is cannot work when passed a single integer. What other dependency requires you to pass a raw into into `hexdump`?

Comment: You were right hexdump was having issues with printing an int (only in python3). Instead i used print(hex(int)). Turns out for this scenario i only needed to change another line from str to chr